# Correct latex format for standard IEEE Computer Society Press proceedings style guide

Tags: conference, computer-science, formatting, latex

I'm planning to submit a paper to an IEEE conference. On their website they mention that the paper should be "**formatted according to the standard IEEE Computer Society Press proceedings style guide**". Which latex header should be used in this case?

\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

or

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

Comment: Do they provide a style guide for you to download?

Comment: No. They only have a link to the IEEE's latex templates page

Comment: **Only the PC chair can definitively answer this question**, but in my experience, *most* conferences don't care about the precise format of the *submission*, provided it fits within the stated page limits.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}` as stated in the How To ([here](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)). You may find it helpful to follow the bare_
conf_compsoc.tex that is inside the zip file with the templates ([here](https://www.ieee.org/documents/ieee-latex-conference-template.zip)).

Extra information

- Take special attention if you should send it in draft mode or not. And also if it should be blind.
- Once accepted you have to include the DOI and copyright information.
- You will also have to submit the final PDF to a signing website (instructions will be sent)
- Finally, the submission process will provide a pre IEEExplore publication copy of your text you ***MUST*** download it because ***this*** is the version that you are authorized to publish on your own website or ResearchGate.